# divs in same row are not displayed together

Tags: html, css, grid

I am trying to split a row in two, for text and an image. However, no matter what I set the size of my divs, they display on separate lines.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
       <ul class="nav">
         <li><a class="home" href="#home>">Home</a><li>
         <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
         <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" id="first">JUSDHFLKSADHFLK</div>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="second">JKSDNF,ASDNF,ASD</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have agonized over this simple issue and checked the documentation closely. Am I missing something simple?

The code is written using codepen.io

There is no CSS and the width is large enough for col-md

Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't need to set a width on the divs if you are using bootstrap columns. If your window is 992px or wider the `col-md-6`s will be on one row. Other wise they will be stacked. If they aren't, you must be overiding the bootstrap styles in your css http://www.bootply.com/6eHIBsKlTD

Answer (score 0):

set your desired width with `display:inline-block;` which will make your div to exactly take the width what you gave

Answer (score 0):

If your bootstrap is loading correctly, you may be loading it on a screen too small for    `col-md-6`. Here is a working example using    `col-xs-6` so you can see them working side by side --> https://jsfiddle.net/mmcshinsky/kgb52j3e/

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to include the external CSS for bootstrap in the codepen settings :)

Thanks for the help!